# How to print product ID in commerce-product.html.twig template

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I am not able to figure out how to print the product id in my commerce-product.html.twig for display on the product detail page. I tried different combinations of { product.field_id }} { product.id }} and can't find it.

Comment: Just a guess, I have not used Commerce in D8. Try `{{ product.id() }}` or `{{ product_entity.id() }}` or `{{ product.getId() }}` or `{{ product_entity.getId() }}`

Answer (score 4):

You need to retrieve it from **`product_entity`**

```
{{ kint(product_entity.product_id.value) }}
```

> Search "Available Variables" for more information here
>   *https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/displaying-products/theme-product*